# Minimizing performance lost in Access based pass through query that is notably slower than SSMS

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2007, pass-through

I have a front end application which allows others to create elaborate SQL queries based on options selected. This SQL code is then used as a pass through query, and is displayed as part of a form.

The pass through queries created are exceptionally slow however. When ran in Access, they range from 3 minutes to 20 minutes. SQL Server Management Studio 2012 manages to complete identical queries in 45 seconds to 3 minutes. **How can this time difference be minimized or eliminated?**

tldr:

- Time to run query in SSMS: 45 seconds
- Time to run query in Access: 3 minutes
- Time to open Access form containing query: 3 minutes

### Structure behind the question

The queries are structured in the following manner

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    (
    SELECT ...
    FROM
        (
        SELECT ... FROM Archive.YearXX
        UNION
        SELECT ... FROM Archive.YearXX
        UNION
        SELECT ... FROM Current.Year16
        )
        LEFT JOIN ReferenceData.Table ON...
    )
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

where the various options are able to change almost anything in the code, from which tables are pulled in the `UNION` segment, which fields are returned in the `SELECT` statement, what is included in the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` clauses.

All SQL Servers are in the same local location, and the tables referenced range from 20 fields by 100,000 rows to 30 fields by 13,000,000 rows

Current connection string (actual data redacted):

`ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=[server name];DATABASE=[database];UID=[username];PWD=[password];`

VBA code which creates QueryDef:

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("GeneratedReportData", GenSQL(False))
    qdf.Connect = "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=[server name];DATABASE=[database];UID=[username];PWD=[password];"
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
    qdf.ODBCTimeout = 0
```

### Constraints

- I am unable to change the languages or software I am using.
- There is little that can be done about the structure and use of subqueries.

Comment: Are you sure it's the execution of the query that is long and not just loading it into the form?

Comment: If I understand your setup, Access is just a frontend to SQLServer. Which means that all the data is in sqlserver and not in access.

Comment: Running just as a normal pass through query takes a similar amount of time, and you are correct about the front-end / back-end relationship.

Comment: So it is loading into the form that takes a while. What order of magnitude is the result of the query? ten's hundred's thousand's or even more maybe?

Comment: No, the form takes almost no time to load. The query alone and the form (which loads the query on opening) both take a similar amount of time. The number of records returned is somewhere between 1 and 400 records. Many of the `SELECT` options are aggregate functions.

Comment: This might be interresting for you https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286222

Comment: It's still unclear. The Pass-Through query when opened in Access takes the same time as in SSMS? Or is that already slow? Or is it only the form with that Pass-Through query as recordsource that is slow? -- If you say *"a similar amount of time"* you should specify *similar to what*... :)

Comment: Running the pass-through query in Access and opening the form that contains the query result both take the same amount of time. If I disable the query result on the form, the form opens instantly. I have clarified the original post and apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Very strange, there should not be a noticeable difference, since the Pass-Through query is executed on the server. If you take the generated SQL, and create a view on the server with this SQL, and change your Pass-Through query to simply `SELECT * FROM GeneratedView`, is that still slow? If no, it might be a workaround to always generate this view on the fly.